# "So you like ducks" what does this mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

Here is the conversation:

> A: I like software testing “QA”, it's my language
>
> B: so you like ducks

Does A mean that B is like a sitting duck https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+a+sitting+duck or is it something else? Is it insulting or positive or negative?

Comment: @Damila has provided an interesting answer. The only thing I could think of that might fit was "getting one's ducks in a row."

Comment: You guys quack me up!

Answer (score 8):

Appropriately, this site grew out of a site for computer programmers (of which I am not one, not even close).

**It is a reference to [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)**

> In software engineering, rubber duck debugging is a method of debugging code. The name is a reference to a story in the book The Pragmatic Programmer in which a programmer would carry around a rubber duck and debug their code by forcing themselves to explain it, line-by-line, to the duck.

It is not negative. Neutral to sharing a friendly joke.

Comment: It's not a pun on pronouncing QA as *quack*?

Comment: @YosefBaskin It could be I guess. You would have to ask B. In American English (I just don't know about others) the beginning of Quality Assurance would be pronounced like "kwah" or "kwahl" whereas the duck quack would  be  pronounce "kwak" (rhymes with back). So I would not think of that.

Comment: @yosef it is also an answer, I guess :)

Comment: @YosefBaskin Clever thought, but I have never heard anyone pronounce QA as other than "Q" followed by "A". No ducks involved.